# QGIS Zoom & Navigate in overview panel itself?

Tags: qgis, zoom, panel

Is it possible to zoom in on the overview panel itself?

I think having done this in the past, but can't find how again.
The overview panel always shows the full extent of the overview layer(s).

Illustration:

- the overview panel shows the USA.
- the intended edit scale is at the county level.
- I like the overview panel to show the state level fe. Texas
- Once edits are done, move the view zone to another place

With the overview panel, I can only show the USA as a whole.
I could create a temporary layer with only the intended edit zone and use that in the overview panel. But that feels awkward and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered adding a view? Click on View----> New Map View. You can opt to sync it or not with the main view.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am dim. thanks for reminding me ... that's the way I did in the past